# Different origins of UTM projection

Tags: python, utm, pyproj

I have latitudes and longitudes from a GPS unit which uses `WGS84`, and would like to project those to some kind of plane.

I'm totally new to this, but after a lot of reading it sounds like UTM is a good projection to use. According to [the Wiki page on UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system), I'm in zone `34H` (a very nice place to live, by the way).

I found two `python` modules to help me do this:

(1) Using `pyproj`, which wraps Proj4:

```
from pyproj import Proj
p = Proj(proj='utm', ellps='WGS84', zone='34H')
lat, lon = -34.228258, 18.413602
p(lon, lat)
```

Which results in:

```
(261762.5589262726, -3790491.0744062006)
```

(2) Using `utm`:

```
import utm
lat, lon = -34.228258, 18.413602
utm.from_latlon(lat, lon)
```

Which results in:

```
(261762.55890839838, 6209508.925565818, 34, 'H')
```

As you can see, the y values differ, but the x values are the same for all practical purposes. It looks like the y values are shifted by about `9999999.999972`, but not scaled. So it seems that these modules are using different origins for the xy plane.

1. Which one is right?
2. How can I change it using either module?

Comment: the latitude band 'H' should be removed, just use `zone=34`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both coordinates are the same. As you are in the Southern Hemisphere a False Northing (of +10000000m) is usually applied to eliminate the negatives.

The utm package applies the false Northing by itself. For Proj you need to specify it:

```
>>> p = Proj(proj='utm', ellps='WGS84', zone=34, south=True)
>>> p(lon,lat)
>>> (261762.55892627264, 6209508.925593799)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#find-utm-crs-by-latitude-and-longitude

```py
from pyproj import Proj
from pyproj.aoi import AreaOfInterest
from pyproj.database import query_utm_crs_info

lat, lon = -34.228258, 18.413602
utm_crs_list = query_utm_crs_info(
    datum_name="WGS 84",
    area_of_interest=AreaOfInterest(
        west_lon_degree=lon,
        south_lat_degree=lat,
        east_lon_degree=lon,
        north_lat_degree=lat,
    ),
)
p = Proj(int(utm_crs_list[0].code))
p(lon, lat)
```